# verilog: signed multiplication not working properly

Tags: verilog, multiplication, signed, vivado

I am using the vivado v2016.4 Behavioral simulation to simulate the verilog code shown below.  The test fixture code is also shown below the main verilog code.

The console output shows:

```
A =   -13
B =     4
C =     16332
```

Also, if I hoover over the register variables, I see the following:

```
ff3 for A
004 for B
003fcc for C
```

The multiplication gives the correct result (-52 or ffffcc) if I instead use

```
C[23:0] = $signed(A[11:0])*signed(B[11:0]);
```

or

```
C[23:0] = $signed(A[11:0]*B[11:0]);
```

Why do I need to use $signed to get the correct result?

Stephen

**Main Verilog Code:**

```
module test1(
           input CLK,
           input RST_AL,
           input signed [11:0]A,
           input signed [11:0]B
    );
    
reg signed [10:0]z;
reg signed [4:0]x;
reg signed [4:0]y;

reg signed [23:0]C;  

initial x = 0;
   
always @(posedge CLK, negedge RST_AL) begin    
    if(RST_AL == 0) begin
        x[4:0] <= 0;
        y[4:0] <= 0;
        z[10:0] <= 0;
        C[23:0] <= 0;
    end else begin
        C[23:0] = A[11:0]*B[11:0];
        $display("A = %d",A);
        $display("B = %d",B);
        $display("C = %d",C);
    end
end

endmodule
```

**Test Fixture Code:**

```
module test1_testfix;
    reg RST_AL;
    reg CLK;
    reg signed [11:0]A;
    reg signed [11:0]B;    

    
    test1 uut (
        CLK,
        RST_AL,
        A,
        B
     );
     
    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
       RST_AL = 0;
       CLK = 0;
       A = -13;
       B = 4;  
       #100
       RST_AL = 1;
       #100000000
       RST_AL = 1;
     end
     
     
     always 
        #5 CLK =  ! CLK;
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because a part select of a signal is always unsigned. This is true even when you are selecting the entire range. So it’s just better not to use a part select at all. You could’ve written:

```
 C = A *B;
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that. It is counterintuitive because for my case I selected the entire register.

Comment: It's better to use the signal as a whole without the part select to show that was your intent. Also, if you change the width, you only have one place to change it. If you forget or make a mistake, it will be hard to find.